# entity framework with existing, non related database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have an odd situation.  I am working on a project with a very large existing database that is completely unrelated, but does contain corresponding table id's. It's as if someone copied the database but never related the tables.

In Entity Framework, is there a way to go EF code first and create the relationships in code, but Not apply those relationships in the database?  I would like to go through and relate the database but the client doesn't want to pay to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, it seems you would be best to add relationships directly to your database (or to a duplicated database for testing/staging) and then just update your entities using your test connection and regression test your app.